# WxPython:How to stop further code execution  in main parent  frame until its sub-frame has been closed

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.7

I am working on a project coded in python with GUI in Wxpython for last 3 sleepless night now I got struck.Actually inside main parent frame I am executing a new subframe in another **thread** all I want is to stop further code execution until its subframe has done its work and closed.
I have tried using **threading.Thread.join()** method but it does not seems to work efficiently and after the Closing of subframe the Main Parent Frame Hangs.
Is there any efficient method to do this thing?

Comment: doesnt wx tell you specifically to launch all frames from the main thread? ... why dont you just spin off threads to do work?  (and maybe see if you really need threads at all ... the GIL makes them slightly less usefull than threads usually are...

Comment: @JoranBeasley  okey...but what about stopping further execution of main parent frame code until its subframe has done its work and closed.

Comment: then you would just subclass `wx.Dialog` instead of `wx.Frame` and `ShowModal` instead of `Show`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a wx.Dialog instead of a sub-frame and its ShowModal() method to stop the execution of the main frame. Technically, you could also use the frame's MakeModal() method for a similar effect, but I think using a dialog makes more sense.

By the way, when using threads with wxPython (or any GUI toolkit), you MUST use the toolkit's threadsafe methods to update the GUI. You should not try to directly access a GUI element from a thread as that is undefined behavior. Instead, use wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent as they are wxPython's threadsafe methods.

See also:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: Mike knows his wx stuff ;P  ... and apparently is much better at explaining than i am in comments :)

Comment: Thanks! You had the right idea, I just formalized the answer a bit and thought there should be an explanation about how to use threads with wx as that can be a sticky subject.